# How to get the date in JavaScript from Date (like "29 May 2017")?

Tags: javascript

I have this date string, and I need to get back only the date (month and day and year):

```
  var date1 = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+11:00');
```

I need to get back only this string:

```
  var dateOnly = 'August 19, 1975'
```

How do I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with the dates by yourself and don't create helper functions. Use an established date formatter/converter like moment.js:

```
const date1 = moment('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+11:00');
console.log(date1.format('MMM DD, YYYY'));
```

Of course, in your case you could just split the string by spaces and take the first half:

```
const date1 = 'August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+11:00';
console.log(date1.split(' ', 2).join(' '))
```

The trick is the number `2` here which means cutting until the second space in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use .toString() and object destructuring to get desired result as below -

```
var date1 = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+11:00');

var [day, month, date, year] = date1.toString().split(' ')

console.log(`${month} ${date}, ${year}`)
```

Comment: This won't always work. In the date string, there is also time zone passing. GMT+11:00. So it can change the date to 20 or 18. you will get a different result based on current time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) with options.

```js
var date = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+11:00');
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options));
```